# Customizing MEF

Tags: model-view-controller, mef

I have this situation where I want to use MEF in a chess project I'm workin on. Let's say I have a class constructor as in:

```
public class MoveManager
{
   private Piece _piece;

   public MoveManager(Piece piece)
   {
      _piece = piece;
   }
   Mode code here...
}
```

In this context I would have several classes that would derive from Piece like, Pawn, Rook, etc. If I put export attributes on all the classes the derive from Piece, the object being passed into the constructor is null. MEF loops through all classes the have the `[Export(typeof(Piece))]` and if it exceeds 1, it passes in null. So I cannot use MEF in this way. I'm going to use an Abstact Factory for getting the correct piece. Seems like the DI part of MEF can only take a single class that has the `[Export(typeof(some base class))]`.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: You should use [ImportMany(typeof(Piece))] to import all instances that exports the base Type `Piece` if you want some specification use Metadata Attribute in exports.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for the `[Importing Constructor]` arrtibute, which tells MEF how to use an exported class's constructor.

```
[Export(typeof(IPiece))]
class Pawn : IPiece
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Pawn(ISomeDependency dep, [ImportMany] IEnumerable<IOtherDependency> depList)
    {
        //... do stuff with dependencies
    }
 }
```

This requires that an `ISomeDependency` is exported elsewhere (exactly once) and accepts any number of `IOtherDependency`'s that might be exported  too.

Supposing you did this with each piece, you could then:

```
[Export(typeof(IPieceList))]
class PieceList : IPieceList
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public PieceList([ImportMany] IEnumerable<IPiece> pieces)
    {
        // pieces now contains one of each piece that was exported above
    }
}
```